# JSON parse error in java

Tags: java, json

I am creating a JSON in jsp.

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject json1=null;
  JSONArray jarr =new JSONArray();



  String email = request.getParameter("EMAIL");

  cc = new MySQLConnection();

String query = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTS ";
try{
conn =cc.db();
stmtt =conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);  
while(rs.next()){
    json1 = new JSONObject();

    json1.put("ID", rs.getString("ID"));
    json1.put("C_NAME", rs.getString("C_NAME"));
    json1.put("EMAIL", rs.getString("EMAIL"));
    json1.put("COMPANY", rs.getString("COMPANY"));
    json1.put("CODE", rs.getLong("CODE"));
    json1.put("VALID_TILL", rs.getString("VALID_TILL"));

    jarr.put(json1);
    mainObj.put("CLIENTS", (Object) jarr);

    mainObj.put("SUCCESS", new java.lang.Integer(1));
    out.println(mainObj.toString());


}


}
catch(SQLException ex){System.out.println(ex);}
finally{try{stmtt.close(); rs.close();conn.close();} catch(SQLException ex){System.out.println(ex);} }
```

As I checked the output [here](http://jsonlint.com/) gives me parse error.

```
Parse error on line 12:
... 0        }    ]}{    "SUCCESS": 1,
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

I am new to JSON in java, please guide me get the correct output. In php I get the correct output.

`{"CLIENTS":[{"CLIENTS":[],
"EMAIL":"asomi@gmail.com",
"C_NAME":"choladhara",
"COMPANY":"Multi Tech Systems",
"CODE":"0",
"VALID_TILL":"",
"SL":"32"}
],"SUCCESS":1}`

Can anyone guide me to get my expected output?

Comment: Please format your code more readably, and there appears to be no need to use a database to demonstrate the problem - please come up with a [short but complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

The change is complete json array build has to be put in mainobj after while loop

```
 while(rs.next()){
        json1 = new JSONObject();

        json1.put("ID", rs.getString("ID"));
        json1.put("C_NAME", rs.getString("C_NAME"));
        json1.put("EMAIL", rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        json1.put("COMPANY", rs.getString("COMPANY"));
        json1.put("CODE", rs.getLong("CODE"));
        json1.put("VALID_TILL", rs.getString("VALID_TILL"));

        jarr.put(json1);   


    }
    mainObj.put("CLIENTS", (Object) jarr);
        mainObj.put("SUCCESS", new java.lang.Integer(1));
        out.println(mainObj.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should add the objects to the array and add the array after the loop to the main JSON Object, something like this:

```
while(rs.next()){
     json1 = new JSONObject();

     ...


     jarr.put(json1);

}

mainObj.put("CLIENTS", (Object) jarr);

mainObj.put("SUCCESS", new java.lang.Integer(1));
out.println(mainObj.toString());
```